# Много тире в единственном предложении

Tags: тире

Можно ли поставить вот так тире, если хочется показать, что каждое последующее действие произошло из-за предыдущего?

`У меня заболел живот – я вызвал скорую – меня отвезли в больницу – мне стало хорошо.`

Если так нельзя сделать, то как быть-таки нам?

Answer (score 1):

"Грамота.ру" такое допускает (см. [здесь](http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=310261)).

**Вопрос № 310261**

> Здравствуйте, можно ли несколькими тире обозначать последовательность действий? Ваш заказ приходит на склад - мы Вам сообщаем - Вы приезжаете и забираете - все остаются довольны.

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> В тексте, который допускает некоторую вольность стиля, такие знаки можно поставить.

Comment: Я не уверен что таки можно так делать-таки. На грамоте указан пример и действия там происходят в настоящем и будущем, то есть тире допустимо при построении **предположений или вероятностей**. В прошедшем времени предположение выглядит странно, так как прошлое уже случилось как факт.

Answer (score 0):

Леопольдик Тыковкин, дорогой! Зачем ты таки наставил столько-то тире?

У меня заболел живот, я вызвал скорую, меня отвезли в больницу – мне стало хорошо.

Тире в БСП.

**1. Тире ставится в бессоюзном сложном предложении, распадающемся на две части, если во второй из них содержится неожиданное присоединение, указание на быструю смену событий...**

Это единственный вариант, под который могло бы подпадать, но тут нет неожиданной смены событий, тут все стандартно.

Другие возможные условия постановки тире: *первая часть БСП указывает на время совершения действия; первая часть БСП указывает на условие совершения действия; вторая часть БСП указывает на следствие, результат действия, содержащегося в первой части*... То есть предикация по времени, условию, характеру действия, с логикой связано. Тут логики вывода нет, кроме как последнее переключение на внутреннее состояние, когда "мне стало хорошо".

Поводов для постановки тире я не вижу, тем более что время везде прошедшее...

Но в конечном счёте, все упирается в один простой вопрос, для чего тебе нужен вот такой плохо согласованный, бессодержательный, но грамматически нормированный текст?

Потому что если это какой-то творческий проект, то никаких правил для таких текстов не существует, а если это нужно, чтобы тебя поняли, то не понятно, что ты хочешь этим сказать...

То есть ты задаешь вопрос: можно ли поставить тире в бсп? Тебе отвечают: да, можно. Ты спрашиваешь тогда: а можно поставить два тире? Тебе отвечают: да, иногда можно, особенно, если очень хочется. Тогда ты пишешь: как понять, что это *иногда* случилась и я хочу поставить больше одного тире? Тебе отвечают: это случается "**в тексте, который допускает некоторую вольность стиля**,(тогда) такие знаки можно поставить." ГРУ-грамота ру.

То есть грамота ловко уходит от ответа, она не может ответить: прости, я не понимаю, что именно ты хочешь узнать?

То есть я к тому, что понятие норма исходит из того, что ты хочешь что-то сказать, пишешь слова зачем-то, для чего-то. Когда есть цель высказывания. Если у высказывания нет цели - это не речь и не язык. То есть да, язык это конструктор такой, но только если ты понимаешь что ты строишь. А если ты просто соединяешь понравившиеся словоформы в некое подобие текста, то это к ОБЭРРИУТам: Хлебникову, Введенскому, Хармсу и прочим экспериментаторам. Хотя даже они не претворялись нейросетевой, по отношению к языку, в их экспериментах была цель, а не голая форма. Они не спрашивали: а можно так, а можно сяк, а какое правило. Они знали как можно и как нужно. Поэтому я не знаю, как отвечать на твои вопросы, потому что они бессодержательны.

Но ты-то мне нравишься поэтому я-то таки стараюсь это делать-то.